# getting data from a listview

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I populate my listview like this from my sqlite database

```
private async void getBowlers()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(BOWLERS_DATABASE);

    var query = conn.Table<Bowler>();
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();

    List<String> names = new List<String>();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        names.Add(item.Name); 
    }

    itemListView.ItemsSource = names;
}
```

when I click on one of the items in the list, how can I get the data associated with the clicked item?

since I am just populating the list with a list of strings I really dont see how I can associate any data with it so is there another way to populate my listview? Even just getting the `ID` would be fine then I could just query based on the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your `ListView` to an object, rather than just a string. If you do so, when an item is clicked, you will get back the object. In your case, you can bind to the `Bowler` object, which I assume has an `ID` and `Name` field:

```
public class Bowler
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your XAML, you have to tell the `ListView` that you want to bind the `Name` field. Here is a simple `ListView` that just has a `TextBlock` for each item:

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
 IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="itemListView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the above, the `TextBlock` will display the `Name` field.

To load items into the list, you could change your above method to look something like:

```
// Unrelated, but generally you want to use "async Task" 
// in the method signature. "async void" should only be used by
// event handlers, such as a click event.
private async Task getBowlers()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(BOWLERS_DATABASE);

    var query = conn.Table<Bowler>();
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();

    // set page's data context to bowler collection
    this.DataContext = result;
}
```

Now when an item is clicked, you will get back the related `Bowler` object:

```
private void itemListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Bowler bowler = (Bowler)e.ClickedItem;
    // do something with bowler...
}
```

More info: [Windows 8 Metro App ListView Binding and Editing](http://www.flaskofespresso.com/2012/01/windows-8-metro-app-listview-binding-and-editing/)